# Trying to deactivate VoiceOver from iOS app, but it still stumbles upon invisible statusbar on screen edge

Tags: ios7, focus, statusbar, voiceover

We are developing an iOS 7 application for the blind, which is designed for fast single-handed use while walking around. Therefore, this app is meant to be used without VoiceOver, but in a context in which VoiceOver is normally turned on. For a while, we have been asking the user to assign the triple-click of the main button to VoiceOver On/Off switching, and then use it whenever they enter/leave the app. However, we are seeking to avoid this, which led us to find that one or several people are trying to make "musical instrument interfaces" that coexist with VoiceOver and have the same need. Now we are trying to use UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction, but there is a glitch with it.

(note that the app is full-screen, as in statusBarHidden=YES)

So, I need to solve any of the four following problems :

1. When dragging the finger to the top of the screen, hitting the invisible status bar causes VoiceOver to find the status bar, and not even notify our app about it (#accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus: is never called).  We need a way to prevent this from happening, because the app really loses the accessibility focus at that point (and neither #touchesEnded: nor #touchesCancelled: is called).
2. If #1 is not possible, then the app needs to receive that notification, so that it know when to use UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification for resetting VoiceOver's focus.
3. If #2 is not possible, then the app needs to be able to reset VoiceOver's focus continually (on a NSTimer) without having it play a VoiceOver sound (and fading out the app's own sound output every time the sound plays).
4. If #3 is not possible, then the app needs to be able to switch the status bar's orientation without having VoiceOver say "portrait", "reverse portrait" at every switch (note that the user doesn't even get to know that VoiceOver is talking about the status bar !).

PS : I know that I "shouldn't want" to solve problems #2 #3 #4 : it's just that I live in a world in which there doesn't seem to be a solution to problem #1.